# laptop cannot boot after clean single-boot single-drive install using ubuntu-18.04.2-live-server-amd64.iso

Tags: boot, system-installation

**I can only offer the following observations:**

- laptop: a hp elite book (6930p) with intel dual core with only
  "experimental UEFI boot support". it's bio setting: UEFI mode is
  disabled.
- I used rufus 3.4 to burn a 18.04.2 live server iso on to a usb stick
  with `Partition Scheme` as `MBR`, and `Target System` as `MBR or UEFI`.
- the usb stick can successfully install ubuntu server from the start to the end ( `using the entire disk` option)
- after reboot, system can't boot due to no system drive.

**HOWEVER:**

With other ISO images from the official website, the same laptop **can** be successfully installed with ubuntu server or desktop, and the lapto can successfully boot into tty or desktop after the installation. Those ISOs are:

- mini.iso  (chosing server option)
- older style server iso (ubuntu-18.04.2-server-amd64.iso)
- the desktop live iso image

The commonality between those successful iso is that: at the end of the installation it prompts you to write grub into the MBR. That process didn't exist for the live iso install.

Interestingly enough, when you `lsblk` all the successful installations, you only get one partition that is mounted to `/`.

During live iso install, There is a 1MB mandatory "bios_grub" partition that you can't modify or delete. After the installation if you inspect the hard drive that wouldn't boot, there are two partitions: one is 1MB the other is the rest of the hard drive. And that 1MB is not mountable with `sudo mount -t auto`. I am guessing that this 1MB "bios_grub" somehow doesn't work well with the older computers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Subiquity" installer is very new and geared towards modern systems with UEFI implementations, so if you have an old BIOS system you'll probably better of with the traditional installer.
The following bug could apply for your problem: https://bugs.launchpad.net/subiquity/+bug/1786384